# Finding Null values in multiple columns in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

What are the best and the most efficient way of finding null values in multiple columns.  For example:

```
Name     Location    Age      Address
Mike       CLT        19       Null
Null        NY        28        Null
```

and so on...
I just need to find out if there is any NULL value in any of these columns.

Comment: What do you want as the desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to know if there are nulls in any column, this could be a good trick to generate an XML file from the rows containing those nulls; it should work for almost any table, just replace 'yourtable' with the name of the relevant table:

```
SELECT 
CAST (
(SELECT * FROM yourtable FOR XML path('x'),ELEMENTS XSINIL) 
AS XML)
.query('//.[@xsi:nil="true"]/..')
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this query. Hope this gives you desired result.

```
Select * from YourTableName
where Name is null 
or location is null 
or age is null 
or address is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using IS NULL in where clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE name IS NULL OR address IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select *
from YourTable yt
where yt.Name+yt.Location+CONVERT(varchar(20),yt.Age)+yt.Address is null
```

Remember to convert all column to the same datatype.